# Count visitors by month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder, php-5.4

I have a question, so I want to build a chart compose of count visitors by date;
I have in my database

```
id          created_at
1           2014-11-09
2           2014-11-10
3           2014-11-08
4           2014-10-01
5           2014-10-05
```

So I want to get

```
3 november
2 octomber
```

I want to build in Laravel, my code is:

```
$aVisitors = $oVisitor::select([
                            DB::raw('DATE(created_at) AS date'),
                            DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS count'),
                            ])
                            ->groupBy('date')
                            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
```

Please help me. Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use here:

```
$aVisitors = $oVisitor::select([
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS `date`"),
    DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS count'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

This will give you something like that:

```
2014-07 1
2014-08 1
2014-09 1
2014-10 5
```

Comment: I get only one result 2014-09  6

Comment: @user3348229 Show how you are displaying those data

Comment: echo json_encode($aVisitors); [Object { date="2014-09", count=6}]

Comment: @user3348229 It should work if you have data in your database. I've fixed `%d` to `%m` in my answer, I've manually checked the query: `select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS date, COUNT(id) AS count from visits group by date order by date asc;` and it also works in my phpmyadmin and get all data.

Answer (score 0):

use next

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%d')
```

or this

```
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
```

in your laravel code it should be something like this

```
->groupBy('YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)')
```

also you can get month name in directly from mysql

```
DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M') as monthName")
```